# Probability bound for perfect matching

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, matching-theory, perfect-matchings

Let $p<1$ be a constant. Consider two sets $A,B$, each with $n$ vertices. For each pair $(a,b)\in A\times B$, the edge between $a$ and $b$ appears with probability $p$, independently of the remaining edges. From this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/222769/matching-with-probabilistic-edges) (which referenced a [paper by Erdős and Rényi](https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1964-14.pdf)), we know that the probability that there exists a matching between $A$ and $B$ approaches $1$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

What can we say about the probability itself for any particular value of $n$? What is a lower bound for it, in terms of $n$ and $p$? I tried to deduce it from the above paper, but the way it is written it is quite hard to read off what this probability should be.

Comment: If perfect matching does not exist, by Hall theorem there are subsets $A',B'$ such that $|A'|+|B'|\geq n+1$ and there are no edges between $A',B'$. It looks likely that it is most probable when $A'=A$ or $B'=B$, and so the probability should behave as $2np^n$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov I can see the factor $p^n$, but I think the number of pairs $(A',B')$ is much more than $2n$

Comment: If $A'=A$, $B'$ may be taken a single point, and vice versa.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Yes, but we have to consider when $A'\neq A$ and $B'\neq B$ as well, no?

Comment: Yes, but exponent of $p$ increases too much.

Comment: The answer to your previous question notes that $p = \log n / n$ is a sharp threshold for the existence of a perfect matching.  This means that, in order to get probabilities for the existence of a perfect matching that are distinguishable from $0$ or $1$, you have to choose $p$ incredibly carefully with respect to $n$.  You might find more precise estimates of the threshold with searches including the phrase "critical window", but that's unlikely to tell you much about the exact probability that a perfect matching exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $q=1-p$ be a probability that there is no edge between two given vertices. For any subsets $A'\subset A$, $B'\subset B$, $|B'|+|A'|=n+1$, denote by $X(A',B')$ the following event: there are no edges between $A'$ and $B'$. The absence of a perfect matching is a union of these events by Hall theorem. 
Thus the following is an **upper bound of the probability that there is no perfect matching**:
$$
{\rm prob}\, \bigcup X(A',B')\leqslant \sum {\rm prob}\, X(A',B')=\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{k-1} q^{k(n-k+1)}.
$$
As usual, it may be improved by using the fact that these events are positively correlated by Kleitman lemma or how do you prefer to call it: 
$$
{\rm prob}\, \bigcup X(A',B')=1-{\rm prob}\,\bigcap \overline{X(A',B')}\leqslant 1-\prod {\rm prob}\,\overline{X(A',B')}=\\1-
\prod_{k=1}^n (1-q^{k(n-k+1)})^{\binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{k-1}}.
$$
As for the **lower bound of the probability that there is no perfect matching**, we may use part of inclusion-exclusion: say, if we consider only $2n$ events with $\min(|A'|,|B'|)=1$, denote them $Y_1,\dots,Y_{2n}$, we may use
$$
{\rm prob}\, \bigcup Y_i\geqslant \sum {\rm prob}\, Y_i-\sum_{i<j} {\rm prob}\, Y_i\cap Y_j=2nq^n-n(n-1) q^{2n}-n^2q^{2n-1}.
$$
I guess that in most asymptotic regimes these two bounds are enough, but if you see that no, please specify which dependence of $p$ and $n$ are you interested in.

Comment: Can we get an upper bound without a summation?

Comment: Sorry, I do not quite understand what does it mean.

Comment: Your upper bound $\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{k-1}q^{k(n-k+1)}$ -- it's not easy to see what this is (approximately). So I was asking whether we can derive a closed-form upper bound (i.e. not a summation)

Comment: We may estimate summands, usually summands with $k=1,k=n$ are much greater then all the others.